# How to display rollup data in new column?

Tags: t-sql, rollup

I have the following query which returns the number of [android](/questions/tagged/android) questions per each day on StackOverflow in the year of 2011. I want to get the sum of all the questions asked during the year 2011. For this I am using `ROLLUP`.

```
select 
  year(p.CreationDate) as [Year],
  month(p.CreationDate) as [Month],
  day(p.CreationDate) as [Day],
  count(*) as [QuestionsAskedToday]
from Posts p 
  inner join PostTags pt on p.id = pt.postid
  inner join Tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where 
  t.tagname = 'android' and
  p.CreationDate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
group by year(p.CreationDate), month(p.CreationDate),day(p.CreationDate)
​with rollup
order by year(p.CreationDate), month(p.CreationDate) desc,day(p.CreationDate) desc​
```

This is the output:

[image: output]

The sum of all questions asked on each day in 2011 is being displayed in the QuestionsAskedToday column itself.

Is there a way to display the rollup in a new column with an alias?

[Link to the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2238/android-questions-per-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an approach like this: [Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120804/)

```
SELECT 
   YEAR(p.CreationDate) AS 'Year'
   , CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(p.CreationDate)) = 0
           THEN CAST(MONTH(p.CreationDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
        ELSE 'Totals:'
     END AS 'Month'
   , CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(DAY(p.CreationDate)) = 0
        THEN CAST(DAY(p.CreationDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
        ELSE 'Totals:'
     END AS [DAY]
   , CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(p.CreationDate)) = 0
           AND GROUPING(DAY(p.CreationDate)) = 0 
              THEN COUNT(1)
     END AS 'QuestionsAskedToday'
   , CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(p.CreationDate)) = 1
           OR GROUPING(DAY(p.CreationDate)) = 1
              THEN COUNT(1)
     END AS 'Totals'
FROM Posts AS p
INNER JOIN PostTags AS pt ON p.id = pt.postid
INNER JOIN Tags AS t ON t.id = pt.tagid
WHERE t.tagname = 'android'
   AND p.CreationDate >= '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY ROLLUP(YEAR(p.CreationDate)
   , MONTH(p.CreationDate)
   , DAY(p.CreationDate))
ORDER BY YEAR(p.CreationDate)
   , MONTH(p.CreationDate) DESC
   , DAY(p.CreationDate) DESC​​​​​​​
```

If this is what you wanted, the same technique can be applied to `Years` as well to total them in the new column, or their own column, if you want to query for multiple years and aggregate them.

Answer (score 2):

To show this as a column rather than a row you can use `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()` instead of `ROLLUP`. ([Online Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120798/))

```
SELECT YEAR(p.CreationDate)  AS [Year],
       MONTH(p.CreationDate) AS [Month],
       DAY(p.CreationDate)   AS [Day],
       COUNT(*)              AS [QuestionsAskedToday],
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Total]
FROM   Posts p
       INNER JOIN PostTags pt
         ON p.id = pt.postid
       INNER JOIN Tags t
         ON t.id = pt.tagid
WHERE  t.tagname = 'android'
       AND p.CreationDate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP  BY YEAR(p.CreationDate),
          MONTH(p.CreationDate),
          DAY(p.CreationDate)  
ORDER  BY YEAR(p.CreationDate),
          MONTH(p.CreationDate) DESC,
          DAY(p.CreationDate) DESC
```